# If / else on HTML markup with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<span ng-if="ItemIndex.ItemCount>0"><a href="#" ng-click="deleteItem(ItemIndex)"
    class="underlined-text-button"><i
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove items</a>
</span>
```

If I have more than 0 item, text getting 'Remove items', right. But I want, if I have one item, text change to 'Remove item'
So,

item == 1 == remove item

item > 1 == remove items

How can I setup this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this,

```
<span ng-if="ItemIndex.ItemCount>0">
    <a href="#" ng-click="deleteItem(ItemIndex)"
    class="underlined-text-button"><i
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> 

    {{ (ItemIndex.ItemCount == 1) ? 'Remove item' : 'Remove items' }}


    </a>
</span>
```

if `(ItemIndex.ItemCount == 1)` is true then prints `Remove item`, else prints `Remove items`.

**OR** you can use `ng-show`, `ng-hide` or `ng-if`,

```
 <span ng-if="ItemIndex.ItemCount>0">
    <a href="#" ng-click="deleteItem(ItemIndex)"
    class="underlined-text-button"><i
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> 


    <span ng-show="ItemIndex.ItemCount == 1"> Remove item </span>
    <span ng-show="ItemIndex.ItemCount > 1"> Remove items </span>

    </a>
</span>
```